# codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, кодировка, pyqt4

Вот, значится, код, который должен использовать простенькую форму с кнопкой и лейблом.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import uic, QtCore, QtGui, uic
import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = uic.loadUi("MyForm.ui")
QtCore.QObject.connect(window.btnQuit, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),
                       QtGui.qApp.quit)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Выдается ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python32\освоение pyqt\start2.py", line 5, in <module>
    window = uic.loadUi("MyForm.ui")
  File "G:\Python32\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\__init__.py", line 219, in loadUi
    from PyQt4.uic.Loader.loader import DynamicUILoader
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 12-19: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Не знаю, в чем проблема... Сама форма (.ui файл) сохранена в utf-8, скрипт сам тоже работает в utf-8... Где что исправить/преобразовать - ума не приложу.

Comment: А зачем два раза из PyQt4 импортировать uic? Сразу вспомнилось spam, sausages, bacon, spam :)

Comment: Косяк копипасты из листинга, не более :) но спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> File "G:Python32 **освоение**
> pyqtstart2.py"

видимо здесь проблема, нельзя кирилицу перекодировать в latin-1

Как раз символы с 12 по 19, как в и написано в сообщении об ошибке.

Измените путь, уберите кириллические символы, назовите вроде "learning python" вместо "освоение python".

Comment: Все оказалось так просто, что даже не углядел. :(

Comment: Python умеет удивлять, если не уметь понимать, что он говорит. )

Answer (score 2):

И мой вам совет учитесь сразу применять ООП модель. Пример.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import uic, QtCore, QtGui
import sys
class window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("MyForm.ui",self)
        self.connect(self.btnQuit, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), QtGui.qApp.quit)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
wnd = window()
wnd.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Можете вкратце объяснить, в чем концептуальное различие? я сталкивался с этим в учебнике, но особой надобности я так и не понял.

Comment: Объяснять разницу и положительные моменты долго будет, просто приучайтесь сразу к ОПП, т.к. рано или поздно вы сами придете к этому выводу (по своему и не только опыту). А если в очень короткой форме, то ооп дает огромную гибкость кода.